# RabbitMQ Quorum Queue - No new leader found when initial leader goes down

Tags: rabbitmq, failover, quorum

I am doing POC on RabbitMQ's Quorum Queues, especially focusing on fail-over mechanism. In my case I have two nodes (for example NodeA and NodeB) and one Quorum queue which resides on NodeA. Now whenever I am publishing a test message to Quorum queue of NodeA, I can see the same message on NodeB.

Now when testing the failover mechanism and stopping NodeA, I am unable to publish any message, also I can not see any messages in quorum queue, I think the NodeB is not promoted to be a new leader. I am supposing the leader would be promoted automatically, do I need to do anything to make the other Node leader ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

quorum queues do not support two nodes clusters and two-node clusters are highly recommended against for any clusters.

**From Quorum Queues documentation guide:**

A quorum queue requires a quorum of the declared nodes to be available to function.

When a RabbitMQ node hosting a quorum queue's leader fails or is stopped another node

hosting one of that quorum queue's follower will be elected leader and resume operations.

Comment: So If two nodes failed and only a single node is alive, quorum queue can't function?

Comment: @SandeepaKariyawasam, that is correct. A quorum queue requires at minimum (N / 2) + 1 members of the queue to be up. If less than that number of members are up it will no longer allow inbound or outbound processing of data. Less than (N / 2) + 1 members can not form quorum to agree on the processing of messages.